# How to set ItemData in an MFC Virtual List Control

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

I have an owner-drawn MFC CListCtrl that I am attempting to convert to a Virtual List Control. I have 30-40,000 items in the list, so the Virtual List Control does exactly what I need in terms of speed improvements. The problem is that my list is owner-drawn, and I'm relying on the value that is currently being set in SetItemData to be able to correctly draw the row.

With Virtual List Controls, you can't call SetItemData. According to the MSDN documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ye4z8x58.aspx) the handler for the LVN_GETDISPINFO notification message should be asking for the LVIF_PARAM for the main item, but this is not the case. I've perused other (non-stackoverflow) forums that have had the same question but nobody seems to know the answer.

What is the trick to triggering the LVIF_PARAM in the LVN_GETDISPINFO message?

```
void CTablePage::OnLvnGetdispinfoList(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
  NMLVDISPINFO *pDispInfo = reinterpret_cast<NMLVDISPINFO*>(pNMHDR);
  LV_ITEM* pItem = &(pDispInfo)->item;

  int iItem = pItem->iItem;

  if (pItem->mask & LVIF_TEXT)
  {
    // this gets hit
  }

  if (pItem->mask & LVIF_PARAM) {
    // this never gets hit
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, a param isn't a display info thing. I am guessing that the reason the flag is not set is because you never/can't call SetItemData(). I don't know why you would need it. You have the iItem which is the index into whatever collection you are referencing.

Comment: That looks like a mistake in documentation. `LVIF_PARAM` is ignored when `LVS_OWNERDATA` is set. Also `LVIF_PARAM` is ignored for sub items, with or without `LVS_OWNERDATA`

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson: The item data is passed as part of the [DRAWITEMSTRUCT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775802.aspx) structure. Whether that is strictly interpreted as a *"display info thing"* does not make a difference. The control implementation suggests, that it is used for rendering. It sounds implausible, that you need to change your drawing code, just because you moved to a virtual list-view control. In my naive thinking, it should be enough to just handle the `LVN_GETDISPINFO` notification, and everything else remains unchanged.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson If all I was needed was text and images, it would be ok. But my rows are all custom drawn and rely on information in the ItemData to be able to know how to paint themselves. How else can a row get this information, if not the ItemData? That's what that field is for, to store user data. It doesn't make sense to have it available for a standard list control, but not for a virtual list control.

Comment: @TonyNelson: As a workaround, does calling [CListCtrl::GetItemData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/clistctrl-class#getitemdata) from your paint handler work? I.e. does it trigger the `LVN_GETDISPINFO` callback and return the correct data?

Comment: @IInspectable `SetItemData` and other `SetItem` functions are not allowed, because MFC source code for `CListCtrl::SetItem` includes `ASSERT((GetStyle() & LVS_OWNERDATA)==0)` If you call `SendMessage(LVM_SETITEM...)` it will fail and `LVITEM::lParam` is not set. `GetItemData` will just return `0`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Will it? Or will it forward the request to the `LVN_GETDISPINFO` handler? That sounds, at least, plausible. Although I haven't tested myself.

Comment: @IInspectable GetItemData from the list's DrawItem does not trigger the LVN_GETDISPINFO callback. Good suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

As long you handle listcontrol external data as virtual, this external data structure could store an ItemData information:

```
typedef struct tagListItem
{
    DWORD dwItemData;
    CString sText;
}ListItem;


CArray<ListItem, ListItem&> m_arrListItem;


void CTablePage::OnLvnGetdispinfoList(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    NMLVDISPINFO* pDispInfo = reinterpret_cast<NMLVDISPINFO*>(pNMHDR);
    LV_ITEM* pItem = &(pDispInfo)->item;

    if (pItem->mask & LVIF_TEXT)
    {
        DWORD dwItemData = m_arrListItem.GetAt(pItem->iItem).dwItemData;
        CString sYourText = m_arrListItem.GetAt(pItem->iItem).sText;
    }
}
```

Comment: That provides a workaround, but doesn't explain, why [LVN_GETDISPINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774818.aspx) is never sent with the `LVIF_PARAM` flag, despite the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/virtual-list-controls) clearly stating, that it were. Nothing in the Windows API documentation for [virtual list-view controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774735.aspx#Handling_virtual_listview_messages) seems to contradict, either.

Comment: The problem is that my list control is owner-drawn; I'm not just displaying text, but doing custom painting (colored squares, for example). The control, as it is now, relies on the ItemData in its DrawItem function to be able to paint the row. I suppose I could just store all this information in the control, but that defeats the purpose of the virtual list control.